# Concatenate Smarty Variable with a String in tpl

Tags: php, smarty

I have assigned a smarty variable as such in my php file:

```
$smarty->assign('companyname', $_SESSION['companyname']);
```

How to mix regular html string with smarty variable?

I want to do something like:

```
<a href="/${companyname}/hello" class="mainMenu"/>
```

But the smarty template engine fails to evaluate properly the variable `companyname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="/{$companyname}/hello" class="mainMenu"/>
```

(note the shift of opening curly brace).

Comment: Thanks! I banged myself against the wall for not seeing this.